# EncodeURIComponent equivalent in android

Tags: java, android, json, base64, encodeuricomponent

```
<script>
    var data = {};
    data.email    = "abc@gmail.com";
    data.password = "123abc";
    data.mobile = "1234567890";
    data = encodeURIComponent(window.btoa(JSON.stringify(data)));
    console.log(data);
</script>
```

Output : eyJlbWFpbCI6InNqc2hpdjA0MDNAZ21haWwuY29tIiwicGFzc3dvcmQiOiJiaHV3YW45OTc2IiwibW9iaWxlIjoiODgyMzg0MTU1NCJ9

I need *encodeURIComponent(window.btoa(JSON.stringify(data)))* equivalent in android. You can check this piece' output in console. Thank you in advance

Comment: Found the answer : new String(android.util.Base64.encode(json.toString().getBytes(),Base64.DEFAULT))